# Why doesn't the textarea become disabled when choosing radio button

Tags: javascript, html

Given a simple HTML page with 2 radio buttons and a textarea, I want to disable the textarea when the "No" radio button is selected.  But the following never disables the textarea.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

.textwrapper
{
    border:2px solid #999999;
    margin:5px 0;
    padding:3px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function disableText () {
  if(document.getElementById("button2").checked) {
    document.getElementById("summary").disabled = true;
  }
  else {
   document.getElementById("summary").disabled = false;
 }
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
Enter plot summary
<input type="radio" name="button1" id="button1" checked onclick="disableText()"> Yes
<input type="radio" name="button1" id="button2" onclick="disableText()"> No <br>
Plot summary <textarea class="textwrapper" name="plot" id="summary"></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Move your script to the end of the body

Comment: use onchange() instead of onclick()

Comment: @tyme: why? The function should be accessible where it is, shouldn't it? The syntax errors, and typos, are another matter of course.

Comment: My apologies to everyone -- I uploaded the wrong file :-(.  Corrections -- which many of you mentioned concerning syntax -- have now been edited in the original question.

Comment: David Thomas -- gave you some up votes as well. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things

-Change your function name to `disabledText` - not `disableText`

-Declare functions with `()` - `function disabledText() { }`

http://jsfiddle.net/4bs1gnrj/

Comment: tymeJV -- I'll give you the credit for my typos.  It works -- I promise to drink more coffee tomorrow... :-)